# IPython doesn't return anything from a statement block

Tags: ipython

I'm writing statements in IPython which should return something, but they don't. For example:

```
In [1]: if True: 1

In [2]: for i in [1]: i
```

Meanwhile in the regular Python interpreter, it works as expected:

```
>>> if True: 1
... 
1
>>> for i in [1]: i
... 
1
```

These are contrived examples, but boiled down from things I might write in the interpreter. Here's another example - still contrived, but closer to something I might actually write:

```
for i in range(0x20, 0x7f): chr(i)
```

I could use a list comprehension, but it's easier to read with each item on its own line. And I could use `print(repr(...))`, but that's annoying to type.

Is this behaviour intentional? If yes, what's its purpose? And how do I change it to the same behaviour as the regular Python interpreter?

Comment: I think it’s something special the regular REPL is doing that ipython doesn’t replicate, instead of something ipython is doing to suppress it, but I don’t know what. Extra data: `1; 2; 3; 4; 5` prints each number even without a control flow structure in the regular Python REPL, but only `5` in ipython.

Comment: Also duplicate of [IPython and REPL behave differently when displaying data without the print function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46029070/4518341)