# IPython and REPL behave differently when displaying data without the print function

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, read-eval-print-loop

Note that all experiments have been performed on Python3.4.3 and IPython 5.1.0 (for python3).

---

Consider a function that returns the identity:

```
def my_func(): 
    return 1
```

Now, this function is called from a loop inside a REPL session.

```
for _ in range(3): 
    my_func()
```

On, IPython, nothing is displayed.

```
In [96]: for _ in range(3): 
    ...:     my_func()
    ...:     

In [97]:
```

But, on the REPL, something is:

```
>>> for _ in range(3): 
...     my_func()
... 
1
1
1
>>>
```

#### Why is there a difference?

Is it because of something IPython does? I've examined the bytecode and in either case, they're identical. So, it has nothing to do with the bytecode generation but rather with how it is interpreted in either case.

Comment: Why as in "how does it work", or as in "why did someone create that difference"? The regular Python behavior was a bad idea, and IPython tries to provide more useful interactive behavior.

Comment: @user2357112 I would like an answer to the first but I'd love an answer to both.

Comment: IPython's behave is the standard behave. It just print out everything in stdout. But in REPL, because it is a basic interactive session, it default print out the "result" (actually not only) of current command. For example, if you type `a = 5` and then type `a`, it will output `5`.

Comment: This behave in REPL makes it easier to debug.

Comment: @Sraw What I've observed is the opposite of what you're saying...

Comment: Seriously? In your example you show that "on the REPL, something is:..." and then there is output in the code block, isn't it?

Comment: @Sraw You said `IPython's behave is the standard behave. It just print out **everything** in stdout` I guess I misunderstood you.

Comment: I guess too. When you use `print()`, you are sending something into stdout. When you use `return`, it won't send anything into stdout. So IPython won't print out anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For how it works, [IPython compiles loops in `'exec'` mode instead of `'single'`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/79921f6fe380f57cf353d76615e4fd8472c83118/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L2831-L2857), so `sys.displayhook` is not triggered for expression statements inside a loop. The regular interactive interpreter executes anything you enter in `'single'` mode. `'single'` mode is the mode where expression statements trigger `sys.displayhook`.

For why IPython does this, the regular Python behavior is more annoying than useful. You rarely want to auto-print the values of expression statements in a loop; more frequently, it'll happen by accident and scroll things you're interested in off the screen.

IPython tries to provide more useful behavior. It's much more intuitive to explicitly print the things you want printed than to explicitly suppress the things you don't want printed.

Comment: This makes perfect sense! It also explains why, on a REPL, `dis.dis(compile("for _ in range(3): my_func()", '', 'exec'))` prints out legit byte code while `dis.dis("for _ in range(3): my_func()")` on the same REPL spits out garbage - the mode.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Well, not really the mode. It's more the fact that you compiled the string at all. If you pass a string to `dis.dis` on Python 2, it assumes the string is bytecode, not source code. When you compile it, you get a code object, a type that `dis.dis` knows how to disassemble. (On Python 3, `dis.dis` knows how to disassemble source code, thanks in part to the fact that source code is unicode and bytecode is bytes now.)

Comment: I didn't even realise the REPL was running on python2. You sir, are a genius,