# How to configure IPython to execute cell blocks the same way as a plain Python REPL does?

Tags: python, ipython, read-eval-print-loop

Vanilla Python REPL:

```
>>> 'na'
'na'
>>> for i in range(4):
...     f'{_+_}'
... else:
...     'batman'
... 
'nana'
'nananana'
'nananananananana'
'nananananananananananananananana'
'batman'
>>>
```

IPython REPL with same interpreter:

```
>>> 'na'
'na'
>>> for i in range(4): 
...     f'{_+_}' 
... else: 
...     'batman' 
...
>>> _
'na'
```

This difference is [apparently related to the mode in which IPython compiles code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46029260/674039), and unrelated to the [display hook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook).  Is it possible to configure IPython to compile/exec cell blocks as a plain Python REPL does? I'd prefer if IPython would not interfere or modify such underlying runtime machinery.

Comment: what is this sorcery?!

Comment: Python's a snek. snek_case loves underscores. Under_scores in iPython reuse the previous output.

Comment: Also the `_` isn't reassigned in the loop.  It's always the last `Out[..]` value (and `__` and `___` are the previous 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the [`InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity) setting to `'all'`, either through the `%config` magic command:

```
%config InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity='all'
```

or in your `ipython_config.py`

```
c.InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = 'all'
```

This will cause IPython to compile everything in `'single'` mode, the mode that triggers `sys.displayhook`, instead of `'exec'` mode, which doesn't use `sys.displayhook`.

---

The possible settings for `InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity` are currently

- `'all'`: compile everything in `'single'` mode.
- `'last'`: compile the last (simple or compound) statement of a cell in `'single'` mode. Differs from `'all'` in cases like

  ```
  In [7]: for i in range(5):
     ...:     i
     ...: for i in range(3):
     ...:     i
     ...:     
  Out[7]: 0
  Out[7]: 1
  Out[7]: 2
  ```

  `'all'` would have printed the values of `i` from both loops.
- '`last_expr'`: compile the last statement of a cell in `'single'` mode if that statement is an expression statement. This is IPython's default.
- `'none'`: compile everything in `'exec'` mode.
- `'last_expr_or_assign'`: like `'last_expr'`, but does some additional AST transformation to print the value assigned if the last statement is an assignment statement:

  ```
  In [2]: xyz = "something else"
  Out[2]: "something else"
  ```

Comment: Note that in default config (which the OP clearly isn't using, but others might) it will prefix all the echo-ed lines with `Out[#]:`, which kinda ruins the effect. Reverting to the classic Python prompt appearance is probably a good idea in that case, by adding the config file setting `c.TerminalInteractiveShell.prompts_class = 'IPython.terminal.prompts.ClassicPrompts'`

Comment: For VSCode Jupyter (as well as other systems, I'm sure), this setting is accessible via `%config ZMQInteractiveShell` instead of `%config InteractiveShell`. Alternatively, you could do `ipython = get_ipython()` then `ipython.ast_node_interactivity`. I think that'll work regardless of how you're running IPython, so that might be the most universal approach, at least for interactive use.